# Is the query over data stored in remote storage by Prometheus efficient? Do I need Grafana Mimir to scale?

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana

We know that Prometheus has three phases of data storage:

1. In-memory: this is where the recent memory is stored. It allows for fast query using PromQL as it is RAM memory. [Am I wrong?]
2. After a few hours the in-memory data is formally saved to the disk in the format of Blocks.
3. After the data retention period is over, data is stored in a remote access.

I wanted to ask if it is efficient to query over the data stored in the remote access. If I need a lot of metrics to monitor for my org, do I need Grafana Mimir, which handles upto 1 billion active metrics.

Also, as a side question, **how many MBs/GBs metrics can Prometheus store before the retention period is over?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparingly. Yes. Prom wont like it if you try query over a few years for example since it will go to storage for everything. but getting metrics from storage for an hour is easy and wont be a problem.

how many MBs/GBs metrics can Prometheus store? Its irrelevant. The retention period is intendant of the amount of data stored. You can store 100MB in a day or 100GB in a day it doesn't matter. What will matter is cardinality